# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cuda_prefs'

Tags: python-3.x, gpu

I have been trying to use brian2 cuda support brian2cuda. I have been able to get brian2 up and working. However, though brian2cuda gets installed as per the [instructions](https://github.com/brian-team/brian2cuda/tree/dev).

When I try to `import brian2cuda` am getting cuda_prefs error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cuda_prefs'**.

I have tried to solve but not to avail.

Thanks and Regards,

vku